# Item span X 2 in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, fluid

I have created a very simple fluid CSS grid which I would like to display certain items that are double the size taking up 4 squares instead of 1.
If square 1 was to be doubled in the image below it would take up boxes 1, 2, 8 and 9.

[image: css grid goes here]

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Test Grid</h1>

    <ul id="grid">
      <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

div, ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#grid{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#grid li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Please check my current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbZBV/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but I think only on the left (by using `float:left`), check your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/NbZBV/1/).

Otherwise I think you'll need to use a `table` with `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: Surely there must be another way? I would like to place bigger tiles throughout the grid rather than just the first child.